# Publishing ASP.NET files to hosting server and back to local machine.Step by step procedures

Tags: asp.net, hosting, publish, editing

I am very new with ASP.NET. I need help understanding the basic procedures of how a developer publishes their site to their hosting server, and then once its compiled and published, how does another developer (someone who does not have the original files), edit some of the code behind files.

For example, Developer A creates a site, uploads it to the server and it works great. We hire a new remote developer (Developer B) and he needs to work on a .cs file, does he need to get a copy of the entire site, to his local machine? if so, does he need to reverse the compiling process to get thos .cs files back?

I am a PHP developer, and since theres no compiling needed, I dont worry about .dlls nor about compiling at all. This would truly help me understand ASP.NET with the hopes that it can also help others like me.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a copy of the entire site.

But you need the basic struct of an asp.net site, and what resource you may need to run this individual page.

The minimal basic struct of an asp.net site is this two directories (and the content of them - if any)

```
App_Code
Bin
```

together with the `web.config` that is probably needs some changes to run to the remote developer.

Now some simple logic.

- If a page have css, javascript and other files you need them too
- If a page need connection to some database, you need that too
- In the bin directory you may only give the dlls/libraries that this individual page use (if any)
- If the page have links to other pages, or post to other pages, or need ajax call from other pages you need them too.
- If some one change some functions on the dll files, you must give the update to the remote developer so he can adapt his code.

After the update he can upload the aspx + cs file on the server.